# Module exports class and function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

Having a class Visual:

```
class Visual {
    constructor() {...}
    async fun1() {...}
    async fun2() {...}
}
module.exports = Visual;
```

here everything works fine. However, I need to change it in order that `fun1` depends on the output of `fun2`.

Firstly, I tried to use it the "normal" way but said the function is not defined.

```
async fun1() {
    const result = await fun2();
    ...
}
```

So I tried another way, to move the function outside the class by exporting it.

```
    class Visual {
        constructor() {...}
        async fun1() {
               const result = await fun2();
               ...
        }
    }
    module.exports = Visual;
    module.exports = {
        fun2: async function () {...}
    };
```

The code inspector doesn't say anymore that fun2 is not defined but when a new Visual is created it says it is not a constructor.

```
const visual = new Visual();
```

Is it wrong the way it is exported? How can I solve it?

Comment: `await this.fun2()`

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use one method in a class from another in that same class in javascript you'll have to prefix it with this.

so `const result = await fun2();` becomse `const result = await this.fun2();`

Answer (score 0):

This is the very important topic of the value of `this` inside a class.

One way to test this I believe is you could have done the following:

```
fun1() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Generally speaking,  you want the value of `this` inside of a class to be equal to the instance of the class that you create because that is how you will refer to different instance variables and methods that are defined inside your class.

So I suggested the above, because the result should be an instance of the class and that would mean you can access the different instance variables defined on the class and the different methods as well, the latter being the issue you were having.

So the other way you could have tested in general, again removing the `async/await` syntax and just going with non-asynchronous functions is by attempting:

```
fun1() {
    this.fun2();
}

fun2() {
  console.log('its important that this works');
}
```

So if you see the value of this inside of `fun1()` not being what you expected, then you know you need to fix it up to invoke the different methods inside of your class and ensure the value of `this` is what you expect to be.

So I would recommend reading up on the value of `this` inside a class, in particular how you can determine the value of `this` inside a class and how you can change the value of `this` if its required.